# Can not import Eclipse mars plugin to Eclipse neon using import->plugins and fragments

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I have created some plugins in eclipse mars. Since I have migrated to eclipse neon, I have to import all plugins which are exported from eclipse mars. All are user defined plugins. While importing it in neon , it shows blank list to import as follows

[image]

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

The shown dialog is a dialog of the [Eclipse Plug-in Development Environment (PDE)](http://www.eclipse.org/pde/) to create plug-in projects from plug-ins of the target platform to edit them.

What you probably want is:

- ***File > Import: Install > Install Software Items from File*** or
- ***File > Import: Install > From Existing Installation***

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply, I have to import plugins using Eclipse Plugi-n Development Environment only. when I click File > Import >Plug-in Development >Plug-in and Fragments, the dialogue box apears. When I select a particular dir to import plugins(which is exported as a plugin from eclipse mars) , it shows nothing to import.

Comment: It is a migration issue, i.e. if we developed some plugins in Eclipse mars, and try to import them in eclipse neon, it will not support is ?

Comment: That depends on the plug-in. A plug-in defines its dependencies on other plug-ins through a version range. A too low upper version limit can prevent installation in newer platforms. But that is rarely the case. With the exception of support for Eclipse 2. x plug-ins, Eclipse Oxygen.1a (4.7.1a) is backward compatible. Check the error log for details.